# jax rs 2.0 annotation inheritance not working

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, netbeans-7

I'm reading Bill Burke's Rest services with Jax rs 2.0 book. However, I'm stuck at this point.

If I create a CustomerService as a concrete class with annotations, my IDE is picking it up as a RestWebService and deploys it.

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerService {
  ....
  @POST
  @Consumes("application/xml")
  public Response createCustomer(InputStream is) 
  ....
}
```

But if use an interface and annotate it, and implement it in a class (the concrete class doesnt have annotations), the ide doesnt recognise it. I get HTTP 404 error status.

I'm using Netbeans 7.4 and JBoss AS 6.2.

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From specification:

> A resource class is a Java class that uses JAX-RS annotations to implement a corresponding Web resource.
>   Resource classes are POJOs that have at least one method annotated with @Path or a request method designator.

You can't load classes without annotations as resources.